# Carregar um volume grande de dados em uma dataTable

Tags: java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Estou tendo o seguinte problema, eu consigo carregar os dados em minha `dataTable` porém fica muito pesado, até a IDE da uma travada. Como eu poderia consertar esse problema? Ouvi falar sobre `Lazy` mas não entendi como consigo implementar.

Método listar:

```
public void listar() {
        try {
            if (listaBeneficiario == null) {
                listaBeneficiario = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            System.err.println("Metodo Listar" + listaBeneficiario);

            BeneficiarioDAO beneficiarioDAO = new BeneficiarioDAO();
            listaBeneficiario = beneficiarioDAO.buscar();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao listar tarefas: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar paginação na sua dataTable. Exemplo:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{seuBB.lista}" var="obj"
    id="tabela" noDataLabel="Tabela vazia"
    rows="10">

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="ID"
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{obj.id}" />
    </rich:column>

    ... outras colunas ...

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <rich:dataScroller renderIfSinglePage="false" />
    </f:facet>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Assim você define quantas linhas por página sua tabela vai ter `rows="10"` e lá no `footer`, esse `dataScroller` promove a paginação caso haja mais de uma página.
**EDIT:** Existem dois tipos de carregamentos de mapeamentos `@OneToMany` . 
`@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` e `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`. 
Leia um pouco sobre isso [aqui](http://javabeer.com.br/javabeer/artigos/materia/2014/12/28/entendendo-os-fetch-types-eager-e-lazy-e-como-tratar-o-lazy-loading.html)
Resumidamente,

> A ideia do Lazy é não trazer objetos desnecessários

Enquanto o EAGER traz sempre todos os objetos relacionados àquela classe, o LAZY só traz quando você os carrega explicitamente, através de um `JOIN FETCH` na busca (quando usando HQL) ou `createAlias`, usando `Criteria`.

**EDIT:** O Lazy que você está fazendo referência é o lazy do dataTable, certo?? Pelo que eu vi, essa implementação é possível apenas com o dataTable do primefaces... Aqui no [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) tem um exemplo de como fazer isso

Comment: Eu já tenho paginação, o problema é que quando o método listar é chamado ele carrega os 14 mil registros do banco.

Comment: veja se contribuí com mais alguma coisa após o EDIT

Comment: Me deixou um pouco confuso, pois tinha visto isso sobre Lazy:
http://blog.algaworks.com/paginacao-de-datatable-do-primefaces-com-lazy-loading/

Comment: Pelo que li é ideal para trabalhar com consultas que retornam milhares de registros e para evitar estouro de memória

Comment: ah sim... o lazy que está falando aí é do dataTable... o lazy que eu falei na resposta é dos objetos da lista, com seus relacionamentos do banco com outras entidades...

Comment: veja a edição da resposta

Comment: vou dar uma olhada

Answer (score 2):

Segue exemplo do código pra implementar o LazyDataModel:

**MyMB.java**

```
List<NameClass> listResult = new LazyDataModel<NameClass>() {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public List<NameClass> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

    List<NameClass> result = dao.findReg(....., pageSize, page);
    setRowCount(numberOfResult);
    return result;
  }
};

getListResult() {..}
setListResult(List<NameClass> l ) {...}
```

**myPage.xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable lazy="true" 
 value="#{myMB.listResult}" 
 var="model" 
 paginator="true"
 rows="#{myMB.pageSize}" 
 paginatorPosition="bottom" 
 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" >
```

Aproveitando, abaixo a solução caso o paginador não reinicia:

1 - Na tela do datatable, coloque a tag abaixo, conforme a ação mais adequada no seu caso. No meu, ao fechar o modal eu chamo um listener:

```
<p:ajax event="close"   listener="#{myMB.onCloseModal}"/>
```

2- No botão que fecha o modal, coloque "PF('dialogId').clearFilters();" :

```
 <h:commandLink onclick="PF('dialogWidget').hide(); PF('dialogId').clearFilters();"
```

3 - No MyMB:

```
public void onCloseModal(CloseEvent event){
        pageItem = 1;

        //pra funcionar o reset da paginaçao. E reduzir linhas de código. O ideal é que o nome da datatable de item seja o mesmo nome do "dialog+DtTable"
        String nomeDataTable = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("javax.faces.source");

        if( StringUtils.isNotEmpty(nomeDataTable) ){
            DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(nomeDataTable+"DtTable");
            dataTable.setFirst(0);
            dataTable.reset();
            dataTable.setFilterBy(null);
            dataTable.setSortBy(null);

            RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            requestContext.update(nomeDataTable);
        }
    }
```